# Simple way to get the current value of a BehaviorSubject with rxjs5

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs, rxjs5, behaviorsubject

Previously in **rxjs4** there was a method in the BehaviorSubject called:
`getValue()` ([doc here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md#rxbehaviorsubjectprototypegetvalue)).

This method does not exist anymore in **rxjs5**.

So the only solution that I found to get the value of a BehaviorSubject was:

```
let value;
myBehaviorSubject.take(1).subscribe( (e) => value = e );
```

This code runs synchronously (I do not exactly understand why, but it does ...) and gets the value. It works, but it's not as clean as it could be if `getValue()` was present:

```
let value = myBehaviorSubject.getValue();
```

Why `getValue()` was removed in **rxjs5** and what's the cleanest solution to this problem?

Comment: The `BehaviorSubject` interface has been simplified - the getter is called just `.value`.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak I do not find any reference to this .value in the current doc:
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/BehaviorSubject.js~BehaviorSubject.html

Comment: docs may be not up to date, but still it works. Take a look here as well: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/test-file/spec-js/subjects/BehaviorSubject-spec.js.html#lineNumber47

Comment: Thanks for pointing this !

Comment: @Clement was correct, this was never added to the documentation because it was never intended for consumer use. Anyone who upgrades to 6.5.0 will find that it is no longer working as it has been removed: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/5085

Comment: @JamieBarker this is incorrect, the discussion you linked is about `of` and not `BehaviorSubject`

Answer (score 106):

As was pointed out by `artur grzesiak` in the comments, the `BehaviorSubject` interface was cleaned up, and the getter is now just `myBehaviorSubject.value`.

I just wanted to add this as an answer because I almost didn't read the comments to the original question, and would have missed the correct answer.

Comment: "*I just wanted to add this as an answer because I almost didn't read the comments to the original question, and would have missed the correct answer.*" If the concern is that you're repeating the comment and [it's not "your" answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343089/1028230), you can always [community wiki it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/184684) (though at 31 votes, I understand if the altruism wanes).

Comment: Seems to me if anyone isn't understanding how answers work it's Artur and not Tyson

Comment: That comment links to a breaking change about of, it has nothing to do with behavior subjects.

Comment: As of RxJS 6.5.4 (and looking forward to 7.x) both `.value` and `.getValue()` will be supported on **BehaviorSubjects** as a way to access the current value https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.x/src/internal/BehaviorSubject.ts

Comment: I submitted an edit to remove the comment about `.value` of `BehaviorSubject` being deprecated. As @AdrianBrand stated the github discussion is about `of` and not `BehaviorSubject`. `.value` **is** and **will continue being** supported in `BehaviorSubject`

Answer (score 8):

Look at the source code to a behavior subject

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/BehaviorSubject.ts

It still has a getValue method, it has a value property that just calls getValue, it was there in RxJs5.

Here is a StackBlitz using RxJs5.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-gcbif4

All the comments talking about a breaking change in 6.5.0 are linking to comments about observables make with of not behavior subjects.

Comment: I have to say that rxjs it the best thing that ever happened to JavaScript.